# Using 2 carousel with different image size

Tags: html, carousel

This is the Jquery that I found to keep the image size still for the index of my page and somehow it changes all carousel img in the html which i also have another carousel and the image of that carousel also changed. My goal is to keep the index section to fixed size and also get the project section work

Jquery

```
var $item = $('.carousel-item'); 
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight); 
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 6000,
  pause: "false"
});
```

Html

```
<!--This is the one i am trying to keep the img size-->
<section class="banner_main" id="index">
         <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
               <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
               <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
               <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
               <div class="carousel-item" >
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/banner.JPG" id="carouselExampleIndicators">
               </div>
               <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/banner1.JPG" id="carouselExampleIndicators">
               </div>
               <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/banner2.JPG" id="carouselExampleIndicators">         
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
               <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" style="z-index: 990;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
               <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" style="z-index: 990;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
         </div>
   </header>
   </section>


<!--2nd carousel-->
<section class="projects" id="products">
      <div class="projects">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="titlepage">
                     <h2>Products</h2>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div id="proj" class="carousel slide projects_ban" data-ride="carousel">
                     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#proj" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#proj" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#proj" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                     </ol>
                     <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                           <div class="container-fluid">
                              <div class="carousel-caption relative3">
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                       <div class="project">
                                          <div class="project_img">
                                             <figure><img src="images/prod1.JPG" alt="#" /></figure>
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="pro_ho" class="project_text">
                                             <h3> <br><br>Classic Design (ဝါးဆစ်ဒီဇိုင်းသွပ်)</h3>
                                             <p>အနံ့ ၊ ဗျက် - 2' 5"<br>
                                                Max ရရှိနိုင်သောအရှည် -22'(+)<br>
                                                လက်မအစွန်းထွက် - 6" နှင့်အထက်</p>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                       <div class="project">
                                          <div class="project_img">
                                             <figure><img src="images/prod2.JPG" alt="#" /></figure>
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="pro_ho" class="project_text">
                                             <h3><br><br>Universe Design (အုတ်ကြွပ်ဒီဇိုင်း)</h3>
                                             <p>အနံ၊ဗျက် -2'5"<br>
                                                Max ရရှနိုင်သောအရှည် - 14'/22'(+)<br>
                                                လက်မအစွန်းထွက်- 3"/7"/9"/6"နှင့်အထက်</p>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                       <div class="project">
                                          <div class="project_img">
                                             <figure><img src="images/prod3.JPG" alt="#" /></figure>
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="pro_ho" class="project_text">
                                             <h3> <br><br>Classic Design (ဝါးဆစ်ဒီဇိုင်းသွပ်)</h3>
                                             <p>အနံ့ ၊ ဗျက် - 2' 5"<br>
                                                Max ရရှိနိုင်သောအရှည် -22'(+)<br>
                                                လက်မအစွန်းထွက် - 6" နှင့်အထက်</p>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                           <div class="container-fluid">
                              <div class="carousel-caption relative3">
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                       <div class="project">
                                          <div class="project_img">
                                             <figure><img src="images/prod4.JPG" alt="#" /></figure>
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="pro_ho" class="project_text">
                                             <h3><br><br>Wave Design (ရေလှိုင်းဒီဇိုင်းသွပ်)</h3>
                                             <p>အနံ၊ဗျက် -2'5"<br>
                                                Max ရရှနိုင်သောအရှည် - 17'<br>
                                                လက်မအစွန်းထွက်- 3"/7"/9"</p>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                       <div class="project">
                                          <div class="project_img">
                                             <figure><img src="images/prod5.JPG" alt="#" /></figure>
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="pro_ho" class="project_text">
                                             <h3><br><br>4 Angle Design (အုတ်ကြွပ်ဒီဇိုင်း)</h3>
                                             <p>အနံ၊ဗျက် -2'5"<br>
                                                Max ရရှနိုင်သောအရှည် - 14'/22'(+)<br>
                                                လက်မအစွန်းထွက်- 3"/7"/9"/6" နှင့်အထက်</p>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                       <div class="project">
                                          <div class="project_img">
                                             <figure><img src="images/prod5.jpg" alt="#" /></figure>
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="pro_ho" class="project_text">
                                             <h3><br><br>4 Angle Design (အုတ်ကြွပ်ဒီဇိုင်း)</h3>
                                             <p>အနံ၊ဗျက် -2'5"<br>
                                                Max ရရှနိုင်သောအရှည် - 14'/22'(+)<br>
                                                လက်မအစွန်းထွက်- 3"/7"/9"/6" နှင့်အထက်</p>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#proj" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                           <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                           <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#proj" role="button" data-slide="next">
                           <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                           <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the image size fixed for only the first carousel on your page, you need to modify your jQuery code to target only the first carousel with a specific class or ID, rather than all carousels in the HTML. Here's how you can modify your jQuery code:

```js
var $item = $('#carouselExampleIndicators .carousel-item'); // target only the first carousel
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight);
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$('#carouselExampleIndicators .carousel img').each(function() { // target only the images in the first carousel
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel({ // target only the first carousel
  interval: 6000,
  pause: "false"
});
```

Note that in the modified code, I replaced the selector $('.carousel-item') with $('#carouselExampleIndicators .carousel-item') to target only the first carousel with the ID carouselExampleIndicators. I also replaced $('.carousel img') with $('#carouselExampleIndicators .carousel img') to target only the images in the first carousel. Finally, I replaced $('.carousel') with $('#carouselExampleIndicators') to target only the first carousel in the .carousel() function.

For the second carousel, you can use a different ID or class to target it with your jQuery code, so that the image size is not affected by the code meant for the first carousel.

Comment: after using the jQuery you posted, the image of the first carousel is resizing as it would normally do without the script